# What is the difference in these WLAN commands?

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux

Ultimately, I am trying to diagnose a wifi connection issue that I have had for over a month. Simply, it connects and at a random amount of time, disconnects (within 5min to 2hours). Nothing I can do to recover it unless I reboot.

Thses two commands below only result in a -bash error, I don't have this command. Should I have it? What do I need to install to get it? I can't find anything but man pages on usage. The Arch wiki has one article but it is in Italian.

> ifdown mlan0, ifup mlan0

These commands below work but I am unsure of what is actually happening and how it differs from the above command.

> ip link set mlan0 down, ip link set mlan0 up

Can anyone help an amatuer Arch user by giving a quick layman's definition?

Answer (score 1):

The `ip` commands is one of the tools from the *iproute2* package, which control low-level Linux networking. It's sort of a replacement for `ifconfig` and does a lot more.

`ifup`  and `ifdown` are usually distro-specific scripts that control statically-configured network devices (ex. when not managed by *NetworkManager* or other ...). It will likely use `ip` and other system tools to set up the network devices based on the boot-up network configuration.

For wireless devices, before the link is even bought up the wireless security/association needs to be set up and usually `ifup` takes care of that too. Various steps are required such as starting the using the WPA Supplicant daemon to handle WPA/WPA2 auth.

Once your wireless link is up you may be able to use `ip` to down and up the network device, but you cannot use it before the wireless layer is configured.

Comment: I actually have both a static dhcp in dhcpcd.conf at boot via systemctl and networkmanager. hmmm... so, i should be able to bring the wifi back up once its down. networkmanager is always connected to the router but it will suddenly just stop for no apparent reason. i mean network manager shows a connection but i dont have internet for some reason. something is going on internally that i just dont understand at my skill level.im waiting for it to quit again to see if there is a command i can use to bring it back to at least keep me from having to reboot every time. it gets annoying. haha